# Replace only one chinese character rows with NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id          name
0   1             你
1   2            你好
2   3          你好吗？
3   4             好
4   5         hello
5   6  how are you?
6   7           how
```

I want to replace name columns's chinese character with `NaN`, if it only contains one character.

The expected result will like this:

```
   id          name
0   1            NaN
1   2            你好
2   3          你好吗？
3   4            NaN
4   5         hello
5   6  how are you?
6   7           how
```

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Comment: `df['name'] = df['name'].mask(df['name'].str.len() == 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask for test length and if exist chinese character:

```
mask = df['name'].str.len().eq(1) & df['name'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]')
```

Or you can use only regex for test one chinese character:

```
mask = df['name'].str.contains(r'^[\u4e00-\u9fff]{1}$')
```

Last set missing values by mask in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = np.nan
```

Or in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].mask(mask)
```

---

```
print (df)
   id          name
0   1           NaN
1   2            你好
2   3          你好吗？
3   4           NaN
4   5         hello
5   6  how are you?
6   7           how
```